# Changing text of TextView based on its size

Tags: android, resize, textview

Is there any simple way of changing the text of a `TextView` in order to make it fit the view's size? Note that I do *not* want to truncate the text or to put an ellipsis, I want to set a different text.

For example instead of `Experience:` I want to use `Exp:` if the view is too small(where both those strings are resources).

I know that I could "avoid" this writing a custom `.xml` layout file for every possible screen size, but I'd like to avoid this if possible. I'm already using some different layout files, but only for situations where the layout needs some radical change to fit the size of the screen. Also in some circumstances I'd like to be able to dynamically set the text of a `TextView` and this can't be done via xml layout files.

I'm interested only in single-line `TextView`s and width.

The only way I could think of is to use a custom `TextView` subclass that uses a fallback text if the original text doesn't fit, but I wonder whether there is a simpler solution and, eventually, how can I *reliably* compute whether some text fits the `TextView` size or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int screenWidth = size.x;

if( textView.getWidth() > screenWidth ) {
    textView.setText("Exp:");
} else {
    textView.setText("Experience:");
}
```

I'm not sure if you need to use getWidth() or getMeasuredWidth() so if it will not work, try second option.

Comment: What if the `TextView` is inside a complex layout?

Comment: Then you can try textView.getParent.getWidth() instead of getting screen width.

Comment: I don't think this will work. What if the parent is an horizontal `BoxLayout` that contains other items? `getParent().getWidth()` returns the total width of the layout, but the `TextView` only uses some of it. Also, how can I tell if a given width is enough to fit some text? In my example, how can I know that `x` pixels are enough to show `Experience:`?

Comment: If you have TextView with layout_width set to wrap_content, then textView.getWidth() will return minimum width in px that is enough to show "Experience:". And this BoxLayout thing, I didn't say that it's a universal solution that will work in every possible case. It's just a concept, I don't know what exactly do you have in your code.